# Does restrict help in C if a pointer is already marked const?

Tags: c++, c, optimization, restrict-qualifier

Just wondering: When I add restrict to a pointer, I tell the compiler that the pointer is not an alias for another pointer. Let's assume I have a function like:

```
// Constructed example
void foo (float* result, const float* a, const float* b, const size_t size)
{
     for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
     {
         result [i] = a [0] * b [i];
     }
}
```

If the compiler has to assume that `result` might overlap with `a`, it has to refetch a each time. But, as `a` is marked `const`, the compiler could also assume that a is fixed, and hence fetching it once is ok.

Question is, in a situation like this, what is the recommend way to work with restrict? I surely don't want the compiler to refetch `a` each time, but I couldn't find good information about how `restrict` is supposed to work here.

Comment: unfortunately, I currently don't have a compiler handy, but if you wish, you can produce the assembly for it (gcc -S for example), and see if it really fetches a[0] every time or not.

Comment: @falstro: I put it [on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/e0GJXt).  See my answer for a writeup on how gcc and clang handle it, but TL:DR version: use `float *__restrict__ result` to let them both optimize well.  clang also manages to hoist the load with `const float *__restrict a`, but gcc doesn't.

Comment: You have the Flag `C` and `C++` but `const` in C and `const` in C++ are have very different meaning.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 | Could you elaborate?

Comment: @Noein In C, `const` means `read only`, the hardware and other processes may can still change it (Example is the result register of a ADC, which would be `const` and `volatile`). In C++, `const` means: It does never change, not be your process, not be other processes, not be hardware.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your pointer is const, telling anyone calling your function that you won't touch the data which is pointed at through that variable. Unfortunately, the compiler still won't know if result is an alias of the const pointers. You can always use a non-const pointer as a const-pointer. For example, a lot of functions take a const char (i.e. string) pointer as a parameter, but you can, if you wish, pass it a non-const pointer, the function is merely making you a promise that it wont use that particular pointer to change anything.

Basically, to get closer to your question, you'd need to add restrict to a and b in order to 'promise' the compiler that whoever uses this function won't pass in result as an alias to a or b. Assuming, of course, you're able to make such a promise.

Comment: Actually, Anteru's pointers are not const, but rather, the data being addressed by the pointers are const.

Comment: @ToddLehman the data addressed by the pointers might not be const, and in fact might be modified during the function's execution.  The `const` only means that the function cannot modify those variables through those pointers, without a cast.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, you need restrict.  **Pointer-to-const doesn't mean that nothing can change the data, only that you can't change it through that pointer**.

`const` is mostly just a mechanism to ask the compiler to help you keep track of which stuff you want functions to be allowed to modify.  **`const` is not a promise to the compiler that a function really won't modify data**.

Unlike `restrict`, using pointer-to-`const` to mutable data is basically a promise to other humans, not to the compiler.  Casting away `const` all over the place won't lead to wrong behaviour from the optimizer (AFAIK), unless you try to modify something that the compiler put in read-only memory (see below about `static const` variables).   If the compiler can't see the definition of a function when optimizing, it has to assume that it casts away `const` and modifies data through that pointer (i.e. that the function doesn't respect the `const`ness of its pointer args).

The compiler does know that `static const int foo = 15;` can't change, though, and will reliably inline the value even if you pass its address to unknown functions.  (This is why `static const int foo = 15;` is not slower than `#define foo 15` for an optimizing compiler.  Good compilers will optimize it like a `constexpr` whenever possible.)

---

**Remember that `restrict` is a promise to the compiler that things you access through that pointer don't overlap with anything else**.  If that's not true, your function won't necessarily do what you expect.  e.g. don't call `foo_restrict(buf, buf, buf)` to operate in-place.

In my experience (with gcc and clang), `restrict` is mainly useful on pointers that you store through.  It doesn't hurt to put `restrict` on your source pointers, too, but usually you get all the asm improvement possible from putting it on just the destination pointer(s), if *all* the stores your function does are through `restrict` pointers.

If you have any function calls in your loop, `restrict` on a source pointer does let clang (but not gcc) avoid a reload.  See [these test-cases on the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,source:'void+maybe_cast_away_const(const+int+*,+int)%3B%0Avoid+value_only(int)%3B%0A%0A//+The+address+of+these+static+variables+only+escapes+the+compilation+unit+as+a+pointer-to-const.%0A//+so+the+compiler+knows+that+maybe_cast_away_const+can!'t+find+a+pointer+to+them+in+a+global.%0Astatic+int+static_data+%3D+11%3B%0Aconst+static+int+static_const_data+%3D+10%3B%0Aint+pointer_to_static(void)%0A%7B%0A++++//+passing+the+value+forces+a+load+before+the+call%0A%0A++++maybe_cast_away_const(%26static_data,+static_data)%3B%0A++++//value_only(static_data)%3B++//+with+this,+static_data+is+optimized+away+as+a+constant%0A++++//maybe_cast_away_const(%26static_const_data,+static_const_data)%3B+//+still+optimized+away,+compiler+knows+that+a+static+const+is+really+read-only+(e.g.+casting+away+const+would+segfault)%0A%0A++++//+and+this+forces+the+compiler+to+have+it+in+a+reg+after%0A++++return+5+%2B+static_data%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%0A//+Without+__restrict__,+the+compiler+has+to+assume+that+value_only+might+modify+*src+as+a+side-effect%0A//+since+our+caller+might+have+stored+src+in+a+global+that+value_only+can+see.%0A//+clang+takes+advantage+of+this,+gcc+reloads+anyway.%0Aint+arg_pointer_valonly(const+int+*__restrict__+src)%0A%7B%0A++++value_only(*src)%3B%0A++++return+5+%2B+*src%3B++//+clang:+no+reload+because+of+__restrict__%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+arg_pointer_escape(const+int+*__restrict__+src)%0A%7B%0A++++maybe_cast_away_const(src,+*src)%3B%0A++++return+5+%2B+*src%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:36.21252948964307,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang400,filters:(b:'0',commentOnly:'0',directives:'0',intel:'0'),options:'-xc+-O3+-std%3Dc11+-Wall+-fno-tree-vectorize+-fno-unroll-loops++-march%3Dhaswell',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+4.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)',t:'0')),k:29.885115337785457,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g63,filters:(b:'0',commentOnly:'0',directives:'0',intel:'0'),options:'-xc+-O3+-std%3Dc11+-Wall+-fno-tree-vectorize++-march%3Dhaswell',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+6.3+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)',t:'0')),k:33.90235517257147,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4), specifically this one:

```
void value_only(int);  // a function the compiler can't inline

int arg_pointer_valonly(const int *__restrict__ src)
{
    // the compiler needs to load `*src` to pass it as a function arg
    value_only(*src);
    // and then needs it again here to calculate the return value
    return 5 + *src;  // clang: no reload because of __restrict__
}
```

gcc6.3 (targeting the x86-64 SysV ABI) decides to keep `src` (the pointer) in a call-preserved register across the function call, and reload `*src` after the call.  Either gcc's algorithms didn't spot that optimization possibility, or decided it wasn't worth it, or the gcc devs on purpose didn't implement it because they think it's not safe.  IDK which.  But since clang does it, I'm guessing it's *probably* legal according to the C11 standard.

clang4.0 optimizes this to only load `*src` once, and keep the value in a call-preserved register across the function call.  Without `restrict`, it doesn't do this, because the called function might (as a side-effect) modify `*src` through another pointer.

**The caller of this function might have passed the address of a global variable, for example**.  But any modification of `*src` other than through the `src` pointer would violate the promise that `restrict` made to the compiler.  Since we don't pass `src` to `valonly()`, the compiler can assume it doesn't modify the value.

The GNU dialect of C allows using [`__attribute__((pure))` or `__attribute__((const))` to declare that a function has no side-effects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29117836/attribute-const-vs-attribute-pure-in-gnu-c), allowing this optimization without `restrict`, but there's no portable equivalent in ISO C11 (AFAIK).  Of course, allowing the function to inline (by putting it in a header file or using LTO) also allows this kind of optimization, and is much better for small functions especially if called inside loops.

---

Compilers are generally pretty aggressive about doing optimizations that the standard allows, even if they're surprising to some programmers and break some existing unsafe code which happened to work.  (C is so portable that many things are undefined behaviour in the base standard; most nice implementations do define the behaviour of lots of things that the standard leaves as UB.)  C is not a language where it's safe to throw code at the compiler until it does what you want, without checking that you're doing it the right way (without signed-integer overflows, etc.)

---

**If you look at the x86-64 asm output for compiling your function (from the question), you can easily see the difference.  I put it on [the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,source:'%23include+%3Cstdlib.h%3E%0A%0A//+I+used+-fno-tree-vectorize+-fno-unroll-loops%0A//+only+so+the+asm+is+easy+to+read.++(Clang+likes+to+unroll+by+4+even+when+not+vectorizing)%0A%0A//+When+auto-vectorizing+without+__restrict__,%0A//+gcc+and+clang+check+for+overlap+(with+a+bunch+of+integer+code)%0A//+before+running+the+vectorized+loop%0A%0Avoid+foo_norestrict+(float*+result,+const+float*+a,+const+float*+b,+const+size_t+size)%0A%7B%0A++++//+a%5B0%5D+is+reloaded+inside+the+loop%0A+++++for+(size_t+i+%3D+0%3B+i+%3C+size%3B+%2B%2Bi)+%7B%0A+++++++++result%5Bi%5D+%3D+a%5B0%5D+*+b%5Bi%5D%3B%0A+++++%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Avoid+foo_restrict_dst+(float*__restrict__+result,+const+float*+a,+const+float*+b,+const+size_t+size)%0A%7B%0A++++//+The+load+of+a%5B0%5D+is+hoisted+out+of+the+loop%0A+++++for+(size_t+i+%3D+0%3B+i+%3C+size%3B+%2B%2Bi)+%7B%0A+++++++++result%5Bi%5D+%3D+a%5B0%5D+*+b%5Bi%5D%3B%0A+++++%7D%0A%7D%0A%0A%0Avoid+foo_restrict_src+(float*+result,+const+float*__restrict__+a,+const+float*+b,+const+size_t+size)%0A%7B%0A++++//+The+load+of+a%5B0%5D+is+hoisted+out+of+the+loop,%0A++++//+since+__restrict__+promises+that+it+doesn!'t+overlap+with+result%5Bi%5D%0A+++++for+(size_t+i+%3D+0%3B+i+%3C+size%3B+%2B%2Bi)+%7B%0A+++++++++result%5Bi%5D+%3D+a%5B0%5D+*+b%5Bi%5D%3B%0A+++++%7D%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:38.96274343585585,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang400,filters:(b:'0',commentOnly:'0',directives:'0',intel:'0'),options:'-O3+-std%3Dc%2B%2B11+-Wall+-fno-tree-vectorize+-fno-unroll-loops++-march%3Dhaswell',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+4.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)',t:'0')),k:36.87541633523677,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g63,filters:(b:'0',commentOnly:'0',directives:'0',intel:'0'),options:'-O3+-std%3Dc%2B%2B11+-Wall+-fno-tree-vectorize++-march%3Dhaswell',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+6.3+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)',t:'0')),k:24.161840228907373,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)**.

In this case, putting `restrict` on `a` is sufficient to let clang hoist the load of `a[0]`, but not gcc.

With `float *restrict result`, both clang and gcc will hoist the load.

e.g.

```
# gcc6.3, for foo with no restrict, or with just const float *restrict a
.L5:
    vmovss  xmm0, DWORD PTR [rsi]
    vmulss  xmm0, xmm0, DWORD PTR [rdx+rax*4]
    vmovss  DWORD PTR [rdi+rax*4], xmm0
    add     rax, 1
    cmp     rcx, rax
    jne     .L5
```

vs.

```
# gcc 6.3 with   float *__restrict__ result
# clang is similar with const float *__restrict__ a but not on result.
    vmovss  xmm1, DWORD PTR [rsi]   # outside the loop
.L11:
    vmulss  xmm0, xmm1, DWORD PTR [rdx+rax*4]
    vmovss  DWORD PTR [rdi+rax*4], xmm0
    add     rax, 1
    cmp     rcx, rax
    jne     .L11
```

So in summary, **put `__restrict__` on all pointers that are guaranteed not to overlap with something else**.

---

BTW, `restrict` is only a keyword in C.  Some C++ compilers support `__restrict__` or `__restrict` as an extension, so you should `#ifdef` it away on unknown compilers.

Since

Comment: You can even change it through that pointer, by casting away `const` ; so long as the pointed-to object is not actually a const object

Comment: @M.M: I'd argue that the result of a cast is a new (unnamed temporary) pointer.  That's why I used the wording I did: *you* can't change it through *that* pointer.  But yes, I agree with your point.  I think the main point of `const` and pointer-to-`const` is improved compile-time checking.  It's not even a promise to the compiler that a function won't cast a pointer-to-const back to a pointer-to-nonconst.  e.g. [after calling `external_function(const int*)`, gcc and clang reload data loaded from that pointer.](https://godbolt.org/g/dnRR6f).

Comment: @M.M: updated the answer with more stuff about the effect of `restrict` on read-only pointers.  I found a case where `restrict` lets clang (but not gcc) avoid a reload after a non-inline function.

Answer (score 11):

Everyone here seems very confused. There's not a single example of a const pointer in any answer so far.

The declaration `const float* a` is **not** a const pointer, it's const storage. The pointer is still mutable. `float *const a` is a const pointer to a mutable float.

So the question should be, is there any point in `float *const restrict a` (or `const float *const restrict a` if you prefer).

Comment: That's not an answer.

Comment: 'const float* a' defines constant address (pointer value) of the pointer, but still says nothing about the data pointed. It depends how you use the definitions const pointer and storage, but stating that it's not a const pointer, but a const storage is really ambiguous and may even confuse someone more.

Comment: @lalamer: I think "**pointer to const**" is a good term for pointers like `const float *p`.  Of course, people will still say and think "const pointer" because it's shorter (and in common usage).  But if you ever need to be precise, this is the most clear terminology.  You can even easily talk about a const pointer to const (`const float *const fp`).

Comment: that is exactly the question I was looking for and the current question is not helping at all

Answer (score 8):

In the *C-99 Standard (ISO/IEC 9899:1999 (E))* there are examples of `const * restrict`, e.g., in section 7.8.2.3:

#### The strtoimax and strtoumax functions

#### Synopsis

```
#include <inttypes.h>
intmax_t strtoimax(const char * restrict nptr,
                   char ** restrict endptr, int base);
--- snip ---
```

Therefore, if one assumes that the standard would not provide such an example if `const *` were redundant to `* restrict`, then they are, indeed, not redundant.

Answer (score 1):

As the previous answer stated, you need to add "restrict".
I also wanted to comment on your scenario that "result might overlap with a". That is not the only reason the compiler will detect that "a" could change. It could also be changed by another thread that has a pointer to "a". Thus, even if your function did not change any values, the compiler will still assume that "a" could change.

Comment: Actually the compiler assumes that nothing external to the function changes memory that isn't declared `volatile`. (Except another function called from this function, obviously).