# Why const_iterator does not provide a base like reverse_iterator?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, containers, const-iterator

Why does `const_iterator` not provide a `const_iterator::base()` function, to obtain corresponding non-const `iterator` like `reverse_iterator` does?

Considering following pseudocode (say, geometric algorithm):

```
std::container< point > universe;
auto it = std::cbegin(universe);
std::list< decltype(it) > interesting_subset = sieve(it, std::cend(universe));
auto structure = algorithm(interesting_subset);
```

where `universe` is all the input points. After `sieve()`-ing the `interesting_subset` contains iterators to subset of `universe`'s members. Following `algorithm()` constructs a resulting `structure` from `interesting_subset`, which consists of references (iterators) to members of the `universe`.

At the end, I want to change the `point`s, containing into resulting `structure` (say, shift them). But equally I want to protect them from modyfining during `algorithm` action, and therefore I used `std::cbegin`/`std::cend` as opposite to `std::begin`/`std::end`. Finally I have only `const_iterator` references to source `point`s.

This is a very use case for `iterator std::container< T >::const_iterator::base() const` member function I want to be present into STL containers.

Comment: What if the underlying container is `const`?

Comment: @molbdnilo :) interesting question. Maybe runtime error (exception throwing)? Or maybe there shoud be two versions of `const_iterator` (say, the  current should be replaced with `really_const_iterator` =).

Comment: @molbdnilo Maybe `std::cbegin(non_const_container)` should return augmented version of `const_iterator` having member function `base()`.

Comment: If `container` supports random access iterators, you can easily convert `it` to a non-const version using `auto offset = it - cbegin(universe); auto new_it = begin(universe) + offset;`. If it is not random access, this will be less efficient.

Comment: @BoPersson Yes, it is. Also for any other container (if it consists of strictly different elements) I can find correspoinding element by means of `std::addressof(*cit) == std::addressof(*it)` comparison. But it results in additional quadratic complexity step to find all the coresponding elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why does const_iterator not provide a const_iterator::base() function, to obtain corresponding non-const iterator like reverse_iterator does?

To maintain const-safety. Providing such function would be very dangerous as already discussed here at length.

> At the end, I want to change the points, containing into resulting structure (say, shift them). But equally I want to protect them from modyfining during algorithm action, and therefore I used std::cbegin/std::cend as opposite to std::begin/std::end. Finally I have only const_iterator references to source points.

Well, you're asking for the wrong thing with the `base`-member. Sure it would solve your problem, but as said, it's just too dangerous. Let me rephrease a question for you:

> If I have a `const_iterator` to an object and non-const access to the container, how do I efficiently (in constant time) get an `iterator` to the referred object?

Here's a fancy trick to do exactly that:

```
template <typename Container, typename ConstIterator>
typename Container::iterator remove_constness(Container& c, ConstIterator it)
{
    return c.erase(it, it);
}
```

I don't take any credit for the trick. I found it from https://stackoverflow.com/a/10669041/2079303 and they credit [Howard Hinnant and Jon Kalb](https://twitter.com/#!/JonathanKalb/status/202815932089896960)

As discussed in the comments of that answer, this trick works with all standard containers, but not necessarily with all possible standard-compliant third-party containers because they're not required to provide `erase`.

Personally, I would prefer that standard containers had a non-const member function that would convert a given `const_iterator` to an `iterator`, but they don't, so you need to work around it.

Answer (score 2):

For the same reason that there is no conversion from `const T*` to `T*`: const-correctness.

Comparisons with `reverse_iterator` are not valid, because the distinction between "reverse iterator" and "forward iterator" is entirely orthogonal to the distinction between "const iterator" and "non-const iterator". The latter has ramifications; the former ultimately does not.

Comment: Calling to ’base()' member function is definitely **explicit** conversion.

Comment: It matters much in the context of the question.

Comment: Please do read all the my aalready existant comments to other answers prior to discuss it further.

Comment: The second subparagraph is evident. I mentioned reverse_iterator just for member function name borrowing.

Comment: @Orient You know best then mate.

Comment: Really, not better. I see you are very experienced in C++. But really, explicit conversion by means of `base()` member function is not a bit more implicit  then one by means of `const_cast<>()`.

Answer (score 1):

It's an interesting question. You want to be able to protect the points while you reason about them, but return mutable references to them once they've been reasoned about.

As a result of reasoning about the points, what you're actually returning is their 'names' or 'identifiers'.

We could conceivably map them by name, and get `sieve()` to return a vector of relevant names. Such a name could simply be an address if we wanted to avoid the overhead of storing a formal name (unique number, text string etc).

If we use an address of a const object as a name, then of course to turn it back into a reference to a mutable object we would need a `const_cast`. This might be seen as one of the few times we might reasonably use a const cast. When doing so we should encapsulate it in a utility class in order to limit any fallout.

EDIT: rethought the solution. this one is now un-abusable by unruly client code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct point { int x, y; };

inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const point& p)
{
    os << "(" << p.x << ", " << p.y << " )";
    return os;
}

struct point_collection
{
    using container_type = std::vector<point>;

    point_collection(container_type points) : _points(std::move(points)) {}

    using const_iterator = const point*;
    using iterator = point*;

    const_iterator begin() const { return &*_points.begin(); }
    const_iterator end() const { return &*_points.end(); }

    // note that this function is only available on a non-const point_collection
    point& mutable_reference(const_iterator input)
    {
        // could put an assert in here to ensure that input is within our range
        return *const_cast<iterator>(input);
    }

    container_type _points;
};


std::vector<point_collection::const_iterator> sieve(point_collection::const_iterator first,
                                                    point_collection::const_iterator last)
{
    std::vector<point_collection::const_iterator> result;

    for ( ; first != last ; ++first )
    {
        if (first->x > 6)
            result.push_back(first);
    }
    return result;
}


point_collection make_a_universe()
{
    return {
        std::vector<point> {
            { 10, 10 },
            { 6, 6 }
        }
    };
}

auto main() -> int
{
    using namespace std;
    auto universe = make_a_universe();

    auto interesting = sieve(universe.begin(), universe.end());

    for (auto point_id : interesting) {
        auto& p = universe.mutable_reference(point_id);
        p.x = -p.x;
        cout << p << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

expected output:

```
(-10, 10 )
```

Comment: `const_cast` is surely workaround (but ugly). Wrapper to iterator is very nice workaround (concept). It would be nice if STL have its implementation by itself.

Comment: @Orient stl already has the concept of a `map`. A `map` maps keys (names) to objects (values). All i've done in this case is taken a shortcut, but the principle is similar.

Comment: 'std::map< const_iterator, iterator >' have a memory cost as well as a runtime one, but doing the trivial thing.

Comment: if the universe was modelled by a `unordered_map<ident, point>` then you wouldn't need iterators at all - you could just reason about sets of idents. However, you're right there is a tradeoff between logical correctness and performance in this particular case.

Comment: @orient last comment. Updated the solution. This one is fully const-correct because it only allows a conversion of a const_ref through a mutable container. It's now optimally fast *and* safe.

Answer (score 1):

A `reverse_iterator` does not change whether the underlying object is const or not and a const_iterator is not related to iterator (other than the requirement to be convertible and the referencing) so you're comparing apples and oranges.

If a `const_iterator` indeed would provide access to a non-const iterator via `base` it would be possible to do stuff like

```
auto const & a = std::vector<int>(20, 1);
auto it = std::cbegin(a);
*it.base() = 4;
```

The standard kindly permits this.

You do -in principle- want to circumvent the protection against modification which is provided by `const_iterator`. But that's what the `const_iterator` is about. So that is neither a good idea nor likely to happen, I think (and hope).

Eventhough I think this is a [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), I answered to the question rather than providing guidance on how to do it properly.

-edit-

If you want a `const_iterator` to be able to return an `iterator`, it is `iterator` that you want.

Your intention seems to be

1. Pass `const_iterator` to `sieve` where `sieve` is not allowed to change the elements.
2. Pass the very same iterators to `algorithm` allowing it to modify them.

You require two different things from one and the same object.
Nobody keeps the implementor of `sieve` from using `it.base()` so there would be no guarantee at all that `sieve` does not change the elements. This is, I repeat, the point of the matter `const_iterator`.

If there was any way of changing things using `const_iterator`s it would just break them.

Comment: What about two different (but possilby compatible) types modeling the same semantic as `const_iterator` only differs by presence of `base()` member function? `const_iterator std::begin(T const &)` and `desired_const_iterator std::begin(T &)` overloadings possible.

Comment: WRT member functions. `std::container`s can provide non-const-qualified member function able to convert `const_iterator` to `iterator`.

Comment: That's not a problem to write: `template<class C> typename C::iterator iter_deconst(typename C::const_iterator iter, C &c) { return std::begin(c)+std::distance(std::cbegin(c), iter); }`

Comment: What about a wide kind of containers not supporting the random access iterators (`std::list`/`std::forward_list` and all the associative containers)? Even if I use `std::next` for forward iterators, then it would be additional linear complexity for each iterator from output of the whole algorithm.

Comment: About the text after --edit-- - you are totally wrong in interpretation of question's matter.

Comment: Sieve just make a set of const iterators to a subset of universe. algorithm uses the set resulting in an output, containing that const iterarors as a consistuent part. But further I want to modify the points from resulting structure after all. Noteably, I want to do it in the same scope, where the container is mutable, not const.

Comment: @Orient: So what is the point of using `const_iterator` at all, then? If not to prevent `sieve` from manipulating the elements?

Comment: `sieve()` is a excessive part of the question (I confess). Sure `sieve()` should accept container by const reference, but main point is user defined `algorithm()`, which accept a pair of iterators as an input, but must not modify the referenced by input iterators range, remaining generic. The `algorithm()`'s output is a construction, formed by input (const) iterators.

Comment: @Orient: So the point is that `algorithm` shall operate on a const container (const set of iterators) returning a structure that itself can modify the container?

Comment: Really *can't* but *should* modify.