# C++ const_iterator to iterator for forward_list

Tags: c++

[As per this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/765148/how-to-remove-constness-of-const-iterator), and ***assuming I have a mutable reference to the container itself***, the constness of an iterator can be *safely* removed using:

```
foo::const_iterator cit = ... ;
foo::iterator it = c.erase( cit, cit );
```

However, this doesn't seem to work for `forward_list`'s equivalent, `erase_after`, as per this code::

```
#include <iostream>
#include <forward_list>

typedef std::forward_list<int>::const_iterator CIT;
typedef std::forward_list<int>::iterator IT;

int main()
{
    std::forward_list<int> m{1, 2, 3};

    CIT cit = m.begin();
    IT it = m.erase_after(cit, cit); // Segmentation fault!

    std::cout << *it;
}
```

So is there any way to remove the constness of a const iterator for this class? Preferably not by iteration!

Comment: related: [Why const_iterator does not provide a base like reverse_iterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33411326/why-const-iterator-does-not-provide-a-base-like-reverse-iterator)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

although I think it's tricky and STL should provide a normal way to do that, there is also a solution by `insert_after`, because:

```cpp
iterator insert_after(const_iterator position, size_type n, const T& x);
```

> Preconditions: position is `before_­begin()` or is a dereferenceable iterator in the range `[begin(), end())`.
>
> Effects: Inserts `n` copies of `x` after position.
>
> Returns: An iterator pointing to the last inserted copy of `x` or position if `n == 0`.

it returns `pos` itself, if `n == 0`.

if you don't want to create a temporary object of `T`, you can use:

```cpp
template<class InputIterator>
  iterator insert_after(const_iterator position, InputIterator first, InputIterator last);
```

or

```cpp
iterator insert_after(const_iterator position, initializer_list<T> il);
```

and provide an empty sequence or initializer list.

Comment: @Evg he just want to convert `const_iterator` to `iterator`, why must be `erase_after`? and in fact no way by `erase_after`.

Answer (score 5):

You have a segmentation fault because you're violating the precondition of `erase_after()`, which states that the range `(first, last)` passed to

```
iterator erase_after(const_iterator first, const_iterator last);
```

should be a valid range. Note that this is `()`-type of range, not `[)`, so both ends are excluded. That's why `(cit, cit)` is not a valid range for `erase_after`.

GCC with `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` [complains](https://godbolt.org/z/n7E7jo):

> Error: function requires a valid iterator range `(__pos, __last)`, `__pos` shall be before and not equal to `__last`.

Answer (score -2):

By iteration you can do it like:

```
IT it (m.begin());
for ( CIT cit = m.begin(); cit != m.end(); ++cit )
{
   std::advance (it, std::distance<CIT>(it, cit ) );
   // do changes on it
}
```