# Converting iterators and const_iterators

Tags: c++, iterator, const-iterator, explicit-conversion

#### General context:

I am trying to build a container that will behave as as wrapper around a multi-dimensional array of run time defined dimensions - in fact the underlying array is of course a 1D array of the total size. The main part is that `operator []` returns a wrapper on the sub array.

As containers need iterators, I am currently implementing iterators on that container, both `Container::iterator` and `Container::const_iterator`. I try hard to mimic standard container iterators, and they should respect all the requirements for random access and output iterators.

I have already noted the following requirements:

- a public default constructor
- (of course copy and move semantics)
- implicit conversion from an `iterator` to a `const_iterator`
- iterator and const_interator should be comparable

#### Specific context:

Standard containers iterators provide no conversion at all from a `const_iterator` to an `iterator`, because removing constness can be dangerous. I have already searched SO for that problem and found [How to remove constness of const_iterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/765148/3545273) where answers propose differents tricks to remove constness from an operator. So I now wonder whether I should implement an *explicit* conversion from a const_iterator to an iterator *ala* `const_cast` on pointers.

#### Question:

What are the risks in implementing an explicit conversion from a `const_iterator` to a (non const) `iterator` and how is it different from the solutions from the linked question (copied here for easier reading):

- using advance and distance (constant time form my random access iterators)

  ```
  iter i(d.begin());
  advance (i,distance<ConstIter>(i,ci));
  ```
- using erase:

  ```
  template <typename Container, typename ConstIterator>
  typename Container::iterator remove_constness(Container& c, ConstIterator it)
  {
      return c.erase(it, it);
  }
  ```

---

For references, here is a simplified and partial implementation of my iterators:

```
// Base for both iterator and const_iterator to ease comparisons
template <class T>
class BaseIterator {
protected:
    T *elt;          // high simplification here...
    BaseIterator(T* elt): elt(elt) {}
    virtual ~BaseIterator() {}

public:
    bool operator == (const BaseIterator& other) {
        return elt == other.elt;
    }
    bool operator != (const BaseIterator& other) {
        return ! operator == (other);
    }
    // other comparisons omitted...

    BaseIterator& add(int n) {
        elt += n;
        return *this;
    }  
};

// Iterators<T> in non const iterator, Iterator<T, 1> is const_iterator
template <class T, int cnst=0, class U= typename std::conditional<cnst, const T, T>::type >
class Iterator: public BaseIterator<T> {
    using BaseIterator<T>::elt;

public:
    using value_type = U;
    using reference = U*;
    using pointer = U&;
    using difference_type = int;
    using iterator_category = std::random_access_iterator_tag;

    Iterator(): BaseIterator<T>(nullptr);
    Iterator(T* elt): BaseIterator<T>(elt) {}

    // conversion from iterator to const_iterator
    template <class X, typename = typename std::enable_if<
        (cnst == 1) && std::is_same<X, T>::value>::type>
    Iterator(const BaseIterator<X>& other): BaseIterator<X>(other) {};

    // HERE: explicit conversion from const_iterator to non const
    template <class X, typename = typename std::enable_if<
        std::is_same<X, T>::value && (cnst == 0)>::type>
    explicit Iterator(const Iterator<X, 1 - cnst>& other): BaseIterator<T>(other) {}

    // partial implementation below
    U& operator *() {
        return *elt;
    }
    U* operator ->() {
        return elt;
    }
    Iterator<T, cnst, U>& operator ++() {
        this->add(1);
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Comment: Why does client code have a const iterator in the first place? It's either because it has a const ref to the container, and should not mutate it, or because it explicitly called `cbegin` etc. and should just have called `begin` instead if that's what it wanted. What other use case is there?

Comment: @Useless: Cannot be sure of it. This container is intended to be used a tool by other programmers and other applications, the reason why I try to be as close as possible of standard containers. I just know that the language allows `const_cast` to remove constness from a pointer or ref. And I suspect some algorithmic libraries to use and return only const_iterators because they do not change the container, while the user of that library will actually want to change where the returned iterator points to.

Comment: The std algorithms mostly return whatever iterator type you passed in - unless there's some specific library you know that does this, I'd disallow the conversion.

Comment: Both the methods you quote require non-const access to the container, so a `const_cast`ing the pointed-to element can't be undefined behaviour. What you are suggesting doesn't, so it *can* be UB

Comment: @Caleth Good point! I had read the refd post too quickly because I could find it there... Anyway that is enough to answer my question and I will remove my explicit conversion. If you make it an answser, I will upvote (and probably accept unless someone else finds other reasons)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the methods you quote require non-const access to the container, so you can't get access to const underlying elements as non-const.

What you are suggesting doesn't, so it can be UB [`[dcl.type.cv]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.cv#4)