# GCC `__attribute__ ((pure))` suggestion on "input state" getter method - correct?

Tags: c++, gcc, pure-function

Compiling with [`-Wsuggest-attribute=pure`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) makes GCC suggest potential functions that can be marked with `__attribute__ ((pure))` for optimization purposes.

Here's the [definition of `pure`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes) on GCC's documentation:

> Many functions have no effects except the return value and their return value depends **only on the parameters and/or global variables**. Such a function can be subject to common subexpression elimination and loop optimization just as an arithmetic operator would be. These functions should be declared with the attribute pure.

I'm creating a small game engine, where I have an `input_context` class that contains an `input_state` member. The `input_context` class updates the `input_state` member every frame by getting the global input state from the operating system.

It also contains several "getters" to query the input state.

Simplified example:

```
class input_context
{
private:
    input_state _input_state;

public:
    void update()
    {
        os::fill_input_state(_input_state);
    }

    auto mouse_x() const noexcept
    { 
        return _input_state._mouse_x;
    }

    auto mouse_y() const noexcept
    { 
        return _input_state._mouse_y;
    }

    auto is_key_down(keycode k) const noexcept
    { 
        // `_keys` is an array of `bool` values.
        return _input_state._keys[k];
    }
};
```

GCC is telling me that all these "getter methods", like `mouse_x()`, `mouse_y()` and `is_key_down()`, are candidates for `__attribute__ ((pure))`.

**Should I mark these methods as `pure`?**

I don't think so, but GCC's suggestion makes me wonder about it.

I'm not sure how to interpret GCC's definition of `pure` - it says that function who rely **only on the parameters and/or global variables** should be marked as such.

- In a way, the global OS input state could be interpreted as a *global variable*.
- On the other hand, the "getter methods" always return different values, depending on the `_input_state` member variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's OK to mark it as pure.
Considering your example in a simplified form with some added IO functions:

```
#include <stdio.h>
class X {
  int x_=0;
public:
  int x() const noexcept __attribute__ ((pure)) /*__attribute__((noinline))*/;
  void inc() noxcept { x_++; }
};
int X::x() const noexcept { puts("getting x"); return x_;}
int main(){
  X x;
  printf("%d\n", x.x() + x.x() + x.x());
  x.inc();
  printf("%d\n", x.x() + x.x() + x.x());
}
```

*pure* allows you to get:

```
getting x
0
getting x
3
```

instead of

```
getting x
getting x
getting x
0
getting x
getting x
getting x
3
```

at optimization level at least -O1 (at higher levels you might need to add `__attribute__((noinline))` to prevent inlinining).

It's OK if the state changes between two consecutive calls to those getters as long as the compiler can detect the state has changed.
If you need to run a `non-const` method to change the state, then that's no purity violation. If however the state changes `on its own` (the system changes it/another thread changes it/a signal handler changes it) in a way that the compiler can't know of the change, then the `pure` attribute is no longer legit.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can mark these methods as pure because they have no side effects.

According to the documentation you quote, a pure function can depend on global variable/external state. I guess this is also related to the concept of closure. You can define a function `f` (using Haskell e.g.) based on an external variable:

```
x=1
f y = x + y
```

the function itself still does not have side-effects (though in Haskell, you cannot change the value of `x`, while you can change `x` outside the function/method in C/C++).

The difference between `pure` and `const` is summarized in this question: [__attribute__((const)) vs __attribute__((pure)) in GNU C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29117836/attribute-const-vs-attribute-pure-in-gnu-c)

Quoting [the answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29117927/683218):

> **attribute**((const)) is the same as **attribute**((pure)) but without any access to global variables.