# What are the [[reproducible]] and [[unsequenced]] attributes in C23, and when should I use them?

Tags: c, attributes, c23

C23 introduced the attributes `[[reproducible]]` and `[[unsequenced]]`.

- What is the motivation behind them?
- How are they defined, and what effect do they have on a function?
- What kind of functions should I apply them to?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The motivating problem is that the compiler has no insight into functions when no definition of the function is available. This prevents almost all compiler optimizations (unless LTOs are used).

Consider the following example:

```cpp
// note: this is redundant, because [[unsequenced]] implies [[reproducible]]
int square(int x) [[reproducible]] [[unsequenced]];

int arr[] = {
    square(2),
    square(2),
    square(3),
    square(3),
};
```

Even though the compiler has no definition of `square`, it is allowed to perform two optimizations:

- Because the function is `[[reproducible]]`, `square(2)` yields the same result when called twice in a row, and the compiler can decide to call `square(2)` only once
- Because the function is `[[unsequenced]]`, calls to `square` can be made in any order, and the compiler could even decide to evaluate `square(2)` just once at program startup. It can also decide to evaluate `square(3)` before `square(2)`, if this is somehow more efficient.

Such optimizations can also be made by defining functions `inline` in headers, and letting the compiler infer these properties on its own. However, for complicated functions, making everything `inline` isn't feasible due to the added compilation slowdown.

### Semi-Formal Definitions

For a more rigorous explanation, see the [C23 standard working draft N3096](https://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n3096.pdf) §6.7.12.7 Standard attributes for function types.

#### `[[reproducible]]`

This attribute asserts that a function is a *reproducible function*, which means that

- it is *effectless*, and
- it is *idempotent*

*Effectless* restricts what state a function can modify. If any non-local state is modified, this can only happen through pointers passed to it. For example, a `void to_upper_case(char *str)` function is *effectless* if it only modifies local variables and the contents of `str`. (Intuitively, the function has no observable side effects.)

*Idempotent* means that calling the function multiple times has the same effect as calling it once. For example, we can call `to_upper_case(s); to_upper_case(s);`, and it would have the same effect as calling it just once.

#### `[[unsequenced]]`

This attribute asserts that a function is an *unsequenced function*, which means that

- it is *effectless* and *idempotent* (which also makes it *reproducible*)
- it is *stateless*
- it is *independent*

*Stateless* means that `static` or `thread_local` local variables cannot be non-`const`, and cannot be `volatile`.

*Independent* means that all calls of the function will see the same values for global variables, won't change global state, and won't change any state through pointer parameters. `to_upper_case` is not independent, but a function like `strlen` can be.

Intuitively, an *unsequenced* function can be arbitrarily sequenced, and even sequenced in parallel between changes to its observed state: (see also footnote 196 in the standard)

```cpp
char *str = /* ... */;  // A
  strlen(str);
  global = 123;
  strlen(str);
strcpy(str, /* ... */); // B
```

In this example, there can be one, two, or infinitely many calls to `strlen` between points `A` and `B`. These can happen sequentially, or in parallel. No matter what, the outcome must be the same for an *unsequenced* function. The mutation of `global` is not allowed to change the result of `strlen`.

#### Note on GCC attributes

The GCC attributes [`pure`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#index-pure-function-attribute) and [`const`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#index-const-function-attribute) are the inspiration for these standard attributes, and behave similarly. See [N2956 5.8 Some differences with GCC const and pure](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2956.htm#some-differences-with-gcc-const-and-pure) for a comparison. In short:

- `pure` is more relaxed than `[[reproducible]]`
- `const` is more strict than `[[unsequenced]]`

### When To Use These Attributes

**These attributes are meant for advanced users who want to take advantage of compiler optimizations.**

In general, you have to be quite careful with applying them. The program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required if you apply them to a function which doesn't have the asserted properties. Compilers are encouraged to detect such misuse of these attributes, but this isn't required.

#### Common Examples (and surprises)

- `printf` is obviously neither
- `strlen` and `memcmp` can be `[[unsequenced]]` ([Can strlen be [[unsequenced]]?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76852833/5740428))
- `memcpy` can be `[[reproducible]]`
- `memmove` can't be either, because it isn't *idempotent* for overlapping memory regions
- `fabs` can be `[[unsequenced]]`
- `sqrt` can't be either, because it modifies the floating point environment and may set `errno`

### See Also

- [__attribute__((const)) vs __attribute__((pure)) in GNU C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29117836/5740428)
- [What is the difference between C++11's constexpr and C23's [[reproducible]]?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76621953/5740428)
- [How to use GCC's pure attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49069095/5740428)

Comment: What was the rationale for not using `[[pure]]`?

Comment: @chqrlie *"The names const and pure are not used because their definition is split into several sub-properties, because “unsequenced” has not the exact same meaning as GCC const and because pure has been used in the industry for different semantics (Fortran, Ada, D, Diab compiler)."* See [N2956 §5.1 Attribute Syntax](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2956.htm#attribute-syntax)