# pure function, why there is no optimisation?

Tags: c++, gcc, clang

I tried recent versions of gcc (9.2.1) and clang (9.0.1) for such code:

```
//pure.cpp
int square (int x) __attribute__ ((pure));

int square (int x)
{
        return  x * x;
}

//test.cpp
#include <stdio.h>

int square (int x) __attribute__ ((pure));

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        const int same = argc;
        printf("result: %d\n", square(same));
        printf("result2: %d\n", square(same));
}
```

and compile it like this:

```
g++ -ggdb -Ofast -c test.cpp
g++ -ggdb -Ofast -c pure.cpp
g++ -ggdb -Ofast -o test test.o pure.o
```

as result I see:

```
    1043:       e8 58 01 00 00          callq  11a0 <_Z6squarei>
    1048:       48 8d 3d b5 0f 00 00    lea    0xfb5(%rip),%rdi        # 2004 <_IO_stdin_used+0x4>
    104f:       89 c6                   mov    %eax,%esi
    1051:       31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
    1053:       e8 d8 ff ff ff          callq  1030 <printf@plt>
        printf("result2: %d\n", square(same));
    1058:       89 ef                   mov    %ebp,%edi
    105a:       e8 41 01 00 00          callq  11a0 <_Z6squarei>
    105f:       48 8d 3d aa 0f 00 00    lea    0xfaa(%rip),%rdi        # 2010 <_IO_stdin_used+0x10>
    1066:       89 c6                   mov    %eax,%esi
    1068:       31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
    106a:       e8 c1 ff ff ff          callq  1030 <printf@plt>
```

as you can see there are two calls of `_Z6squarei`,
but why? I marked function as pure, and use the same argument,
why gcc and clang can not remove the second call?

Comment: Does `__attribute__ ((const))` work?

Comment: I suspect that `__attribute__ ((pure))` is a directive to the _optimizer_.

Comment: If you compile with `-O2`, the function is inlined _and_ only calculated _once_. The result is computed/saved in `%ebx` and that is moved into `%esi` [as second arg to `printf`]. For the second `printf` call, `%ebx` is _not_ recalculated but merely moved to `%esi` again. If you force `gcc` to _not_ inline [via `-fno-inline`], then `square` _is_ called but only _once_ [and, again, the computed value is saved in `%ebx`]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that while `square()` is marked pure, `printf()` isn't. So the compiler is not free to assume that all state is the same after a call to `printf()`, and so `square()` itself might read different state and thus produce different output. However, it should be fine if you call `square()` twice without any other function call inbetween:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        const int same = argc;
        int x = square(same);
        int y = square(same);
        printf("result: %d\n", x);
        printf("result2: %d\n", y);
}
```

As eerorika mentioned, `__attribute__((const))` will work because it adds the further restriction that `square()` may not read any state except its inputs. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29117836/attribute-const-vs-attribute-pure-in-gnu-c) about the difference between pure and const.